# How to use Core NFC with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, core-nfc

I can't implement NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate in SwiftUI

[image]

So I create a class to implement it

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var out="n/a"

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(out)
            Button(
                action:{
                    self.scan()
                },
                label:{Text("Scan")}
            )
        }
    }

    func scan(){
        var nfc=Nfc()
        nfc.start()
        out = ???
    }
}
```

Nfc.swift

```
class Nfc: NSObject, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate{

    func start(){
        let session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
        session.begin()
        print("start")
    }
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("didInvalidateWithError")
    }
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        print("scan")
    }
    func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession) {
        print("readerSessionDidBecomeActive")
    }
}
```

I can successfully scan the NFC tag, but it did not trigger any callback, only show me this error

```
[CoreNFC] 00000002 81bfda80 -[NFCNDEFReaderSession _callbackDidBecomeActive]:228  Delegate does not implement -readerSessionDidBecomeActive: method
```

But I actually implemented this method.

If I add this method, I cannot scan the tag.

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCNDEFTag]) {
    print("didDetect")
}
```

Comment: Here is an example project on GitHub showing how to use NFC with SwiftUI: https://github.com/robbiet480/TransitPal

Comment: I have the exact same problem. My code looks almost identical to yours. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view that will conform to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and the view has a `Coordinator` that handles all the delegate functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to the SwiftUI implementation, just add the `readerSessionDidBecomeActive` callback to your `Nfc` class:

```
public func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession) {
   print("readerSessionDidBecomeActive")
}
```